# Adding C/C++ like pre-processing ability to your program

Tags: c++, parsing, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have a C++ program that processes an input file. I want to add pre-processing ability to my program. That is say the input file looks like :

```
%pre-processing section
#include <some_parent_file>
#define x y
#ifdef 0
some useless text
#endif

%actual file-contents
... lots of text ...
```

Then my program should automatically include the text from parent file, do the #define stuff and other pre-processing. I could use a script (with g++ -E) before calling my program but I would like to be able to do this within my program as that allows more flexibility.

Also "g++ -E" will assume a pre-processor directive when lines in the "actual file-contents" section start with a hash (g++ -E doesn't know that I want to separate my code into 2 sections!).

Moreover, if I can use **just** the ifdef functionality within "actual file contents" section, that would be amazing.

**Can I embed C++ code within my program to use only the features I want from pre-processing capability of gcc compiler ?**

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Just have your program fork a process to run g++ -E on the provided file, and process the result.

Comment: As long as you don't get too crazy in your macros it all looks fairly simple to implement. What's your question?

Comment: How complex do you want to get? I recently rolled my own functionality for `#if`, `#else`, `#elif`, and `#endif` as well as verrrry basic boolean support for `&&` and `||`. `#include` would be trivial. `#define` would be tricky depending on how complex your input could be.

Comment: yes, I can implement this from scratch but want to avoid re-inventing the wheel ...

Comment: I think the GCC preprocessor is a library in the GCC source. Maybe it's possible to use that?

Answer (score 2):

How about a library like [Wave](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/wave_preprocessor.aspx) or [cpplib](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/)?

Answer (score 1):

A simple possibility would be to use `popen` to read from a command pipe, which could be `cpp` (or `gcc -C -E`) or `m4`.

A related possibility is to *embed a scripting interpreter* in your program, e.g. [lua](http://www.lua.org/). A related solution is to *make your application embedded in an interpreter* like [Python](http://docs.python.org/py3k/c-api/index.html) or [Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual032.html).

At last, you could use ordinary [lexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexing) and [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques, perhaps with [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/) and process yourself your include directives. You can also use library for configuration files, like [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/)

Comment: The objective is to NOT USE SCRIPTING and NOT WRITING EVERYTHING FROM SCRATCH in c++, as this is something gcc compiler already can do (I do not want to check for include paths and such).

Basically, is there a way to do this within C++ (using systems calls or such) that allows me to use only the features of pre-processing that I require.

Comment: The **GCC compiler** is **not involved** at all **when running** your application (unless you invoke it thru `popen` or `system` or `execve`). It is only used to build the executable...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to turn on/off features at compile time, it is best to stick to standard preprocessor macros or use templates. You can also look at how Qt parses the standard C++ code to generate additional code. At runtime, you can achieve this with scripting or maybe a plug-in system.